# dataTable only refreshed After Site refresh

Tags: ajax, jsf, command

I use primefaces and the dataTable component. On my Site i have several forms which i use to collect Data and persist it in the Database. This is triggered by a p:command Button, which Attribute “Update“ contains the id of the dataTable showing the DB contents. When i submit the Form the component (table) is Not updated. What could be wrong?

Comment: Provide a minimal code example to demonstrate your problem!

Answer (score 0):

not an answer but a question to help divine the point of failure.  is the datatable in a separate form from the commandButton?  if so, assuming you're using ajax="true" (the default for pf components), how are you referencing the table to make sure it updates.  if you're not using ajax, i'm guessing it's a stale data issue in the backing bean.  but without more info, it's hard.  try attaching source code (stripped down to your comfort level if you're working on something sensitive).

HTH